# Why won't an NSWindow restore its state (using Resume in Lion)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nswindow, resume

I'm working on implementing Resume in my formerly Snow Leopard app. For my app's main window, I checked the `Restorable` checkbox in Interface Builder, and everything's working fine. Its delegate has `-window:willEncodeRestorableState:state` and `-window:didDecodeRestorableState:` called on it, just fine. Everything works.

I have another window that is also going to sometimes be open when the user quits. I checked `Restorable` for it, and implemented the two methods above. `..willEncode..` gets called when I quit with the window open, but `..didDecode..` never gets called, and the window doesn't get restored. I've read through the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) and it seemed like I may want to create a **restoration class**, but the docs weren't particularly clear on how to do so.

I tried implementing the `<NSWindowRestoration>` protocol in my AppDelegate, and in my second restorable window's delegate, but the `+restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:` method never got called for either of them.

What am I missing? Am I on the right track with [`NSWindowRestoration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSWindowRestoration_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) but not doing it right? The way the docs talked about the restoration class, it sounded like there would only be one. Do I need to specify it in the app's plist or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the above linked [Resume documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) neglects to mention is `NSWindow`'s [`-restorationClass`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/restorationClass) property. If you set this property in code (to a class that implements `<NSWindowRestoration>`, then that class is responsible for creating the window.